# Dummy Coding ANCOVA in spss

Tags: ancova

Scenario: 
1 continuous DV = problem solving ability
1 categorical IV = exposure, no exposure
1 categorical covariate = previous preference (like, dislike, neutral)

How do I dummy code the covariate in spss?
I don't want to perform a regression and/or use the covariate as a factor.

Is the following dummy coding correct?
DummyLike: like = 1, dislike = 0, neutral = 0
DummyDislike: like = 0, dislike = 1, neutral = 0
DummyNeutral: like = 0, dislike = 0, neutral = 1

Do I then enter 3 covariates (vs. the original covariate/previous preference, into the covariate box when I run the analysis in spss?

Thank you.

Comment: SPSS will do the dummy coding for you.